# Is there any way to hide excess buttons from CKEditor toolbar?

Tags: ckeditor

I wanna clean up my CKEditor setup, but without removing some seldom-used buttons. I like the approach on Google Drive, where excess buttons at the end of the toolbar get hidden inside a dropdown menu.

Is it possible to do the same on CKEditor?

[image: Google Drive "More" button]

Comment: Are you asking for a plug-in recommendation?...

Comment: not exactly sure. it might be done by a plugin, but I didn't find any from prior research. I didn't find an easy way to implement that by hand - but I'm far from being an expert in this field. Finally, I was really expecting this to be a feature toggled by an option, but it seems I could be asking too much?

Comment: I'm not really familiar with the editor/IDE, so I can't help much. Unfortunately, your title suggests you're asking for a 3rd party plug-in and/or recommendation, which is off-topic. I just asked to clarify. You may have better luck visiting their support/forums or something.

Comment: their support forum is closed, and they specifically point to SO for support. It became their official support channel :)
I'll rephrase the title nonetheless, you're right on it sounding off-topic.

Comment: Them giving you that kind of response leaves a lot to be desired, IMHO. Good luck.